# Select2 - Deny to can clean the input field and disable the form if results not found

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, coffeescript, jquery-select2

I have this json file on `/api/searches`:

```
[{"id":"513dbb61a61654a845000005","text":"ingeniero agrónomo"},{"id":"513a11d4a6165411b2000008","text":"ingeniero industrial"}]
```

I'm using select2 to show results.

This is my current select2 setting:

```
$('#query_txt').select2
  createSearchChoice: (term, data) ->
    if $(data).filter(->
      @text.localeCompare(term) is 0
    ).length is 0
      id: term
      text: term
  width: 'resolve'
  minimumInputLength: 3
  tags: true
  showSearchBox: true
  maximumSelectionSize: 1
  closeOnSelect: true
  multiple: false
  selectOnBlur: true
  ajax:
    url: "/api/v1/cvs/searches"
    quietMillis: 100
    dataType: 'json'
    data: (term, page) ->
      q: term, 
      page_limit: 9
    results: (data, page) ->
      results: data
  initSelection: (element, callback) ->
    $.get "/api/searches/" + element.val(), (data) ->
      callback {id: data.id, text: data.occupation}
```

In this example, http://jsfiddle.net/nqWNJ/6/ or http://jsfiddle.net/uDrvp/1/ if you type on text field the word `"asdfasdf"` or random word, and if you click output of the input field, the keyword remains inside the input and this keyword is not **deleted** by select2.

**I would like, if no results are found or the user clicks outside the text field, the keyword is not removed and my form is not disabled**

How can I achieve this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to add `selectOnBlur:true` option to your config and upgrade to latest master. here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nqWNJ/7/

Comment: Thank you Igor, with `selectOnBlur: true` and `createSearchChoice` is working fine. However with `createSearchChoice` appear as suggestions all user is writing. I don't need this feature. I want only showing suggestion if is founded in json. If suggestion is not found in json is possible show a message like `formatNoMatches: (term) ->
          "<a href='#' id='new_search'>Search with these terms</a>"` I have edited my code. Thank you again Igor!