# Select2 - disable the user input choice

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I'm trying to set datas from ajax in a select2 select...

But the problem is that if I write something which isn't in my datas i can select this choice !

[image]

And this will take this value "I don't exist" ... The formatNoMatches() function seems not to be called ...

**JS :**

```
$(".select2-ajax").select2({
ajax: {
url: "ajax.call.php",
type:'POST',
dataType: 'json',
data: function (params) {
  return {
    nom: params.term, // search chars
    page: params.page,
  };
},
processResults: function (data, page) {
console.log(data.data);
if(typeof(data.data)=='undefined' || !data.data || data.data.length <= 0)
  var res = [];
else
{
  var res = [];
  for (var i = data.data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
  {
    res.push({"text":data.data[i]["nom"]+' '+data.data[i]["prenom"],"id":data.data[i]["id_salarie"]});
  };
}
return { results: res};
},
cache: true
 },
formatNoMatches: function( term ) {
return "<li class='select2-no-results'>' "+term+" ': Aucun  résultat</li>";
},

allowClear: true,
language: 'fr',
multiple: false,
```

I tried the two following after seeing [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15436782/select2-deny-to-can-clean-the-input-field-and-disable-the-form-if-results-not) question : ( but still don't work )

```
selectOnBlur:false,
createSearchChoice: false,



escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; },
minimumInputLength: 1,
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should only happen if you are returning an option from your server that matches the text the user entered **or** you are using the `tags` option.

Since you don't appear to be using `tags`, and your code doesn't include it, you can ensure this is not the issue by overriding `createTag` (previously `createSearchChoice` to always return `null`.

```
$('select').select2({
  createTag: function () {
    // Disable tagging
    return null;
  }
});
```

Comment: @Kevin Brown is there a way to completely disable user input in that select box?

Answer (score 3):

Set tags to false. Example:

$('select').select2({
  tags: false
});